# JS/Jquery youtube video won't play

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, youtube, adobe-analytics

this is the link to my site :
http://www.cimbbank.com.my/en/business/products/cash-management/collections-cimb/plug-n-pay-by-cimb-bank.html

Been fiddling around to figure out why the youtube video won't play. 
I'm not sure what I missed. It's not playing. I have two iframes for both videos. My guess is that there's nothing wrong with my css.

This is my js for the youtube component:

```
  function getFrameID(id) {
        var elem = document.getElementById(id);
        if (elem) {
            if (/^iframe$/i.test(elem.tagName)) return id; //Frame, OK
            // else: Look for frame
            var elems = elem.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
            if (!elems.length) return null; //No iframe found, FAILURE
            for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                if (/^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com(\/|$)/i.test(elems[i].src)) break;
            }
            elem = elems[i]; //The only, or the best iFrame
            if (elem.id) return elem.id; //Existing ID, return it
            // else: Create a new ID
            do { //Keep postfixing `-frame` until the ID is unique
                id += "-frame";
            } while (document.getElementById(id));
            elem.id = id;
            return id;
        }
        // If no element, return null.
        return null;
    }

    // Define YT_ready function.
    var YT_ready = (function() {
        var onReady_funcs = [],
            api_isReady = false;
    /* @param func function     Function to execute on ready
             * @param func Boolean      If true, all qeued functions are executed
             * @param b_before Boolean  If true, the func will added to the first
                                         position in the queue*/
        return function(func, b_before) {
            if (func === true) {
                api_isReady = true;
                for (var i = 0; i < onReady_funcs.length; i++) {
                    // Removes the first func from the array, and execute func
                    onReady_funcs.shift()();
                }
            }
            else if (typeof func == "function") {
                if (api_isReady) func();
                else onReady_funcs[b_before ? "unshift" : "push"](func);
            }
        }
    })();
    // This function will be called when the API is fully loaded

    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        YT_ready(true)
    }

    var players = {};
    //Define a player storage object, to enable later function calls,
    //  without having to create a new class instance again.
    YT_ready(function() {
        $(".youtube_overlay_thumb + iframe[id]").each(function() {
            var identifier = this.id;
            var frameID = getFrameID(identifier);
            if (frameID) { //If the frame exists
                players[frameID] = new YT.Player(frameID, {
                    events: {
                        "onReady": createYTEvent(frameID, identifier)
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });


    // Returns a function to enable multiple events
    function createYTEvent(frameID, identifier) {
        return function (event) {
            var player = players[frameID]; // player object
            var the_div = $('#'+identifier).parent();
            the_div.children('.youtube_overlay_thumb').click(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.fadeOut().next().addClass('play');
                if ($this.next().hasClass('play')) {
                    player.playVideo();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    (function(){ //Closure, to not leak to the scope
      var s = document.createElement("script");
      s.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api"; /* Load Player API*/
      var before = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      before.parentNode.insertBefore(s, before);
    })();

    // Etc

    $('.youtube_overlay_thumb').click(function(){
    var videoname = $('.videoname').val();
        s.linkTrackVars = "events,eVar24,prop24";
        s.linkTrackEvents = "event19";
        s.events = "event19";
        s.eVar24 = videoname;
        s.prop24 = videoname;
    s.tl(this,'o','youtube-video-player');
    })
```

Comment: @Abhijeet I'm using chrome, I checked it other computers and it's not playing

Comment: I think your most immediate issue is this: `".youtube_overlay_thumb + iframe[id]"` I think you probably meant to break out of quote and do this: `".youtube_overlay_thumb" + iframe[id]` but I don't see where you are defining `iframe` or `id` so that looks like your next issue to figure out. Maybe instead use selector `"[class*='youtube_overlay_thumb']"`

Answer (score 0):

I tried playing your video from chrome browser. Console is showing me that `playVideo()` of `player` is undefined. There might be some problem in initializing `player` which is responsible for issue for playing youtube video. Just check whether your initializing `player` properly.

Comment: Checked my player. Don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: When I played video I'm getting playVideo() is undefined means your player var is not getting initialized. Try printing var players attributes on console in before playing video if 
($this.next().hasClass('play')) 
{
                    //Print player attributes on console
                    player.playVideo();
}